# How to write to an XML file from iOS?

Tags: ios, xml, libxml2

I am developing an app for iPad, and I need to modify several attributes in a XML file at runtime.

I found the class [NSXMLDocument](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsxmldocument). But I haven't been able to import it to my project.

Is this class not available for iPhone/iPad development?

Is there some other approach I can consider?

I read about libxml library. Is it my answer or there is a better approach?

Answer (score 2):

`NSXMLDocument` is MacOS X Cocoa only.  You have available on iPhone `NSXMLParser`, and several external libraries built on libxml2 - `TouchXML`, `KissXML` and a couple of others.

Note that [KissXML](https://github.com/robbiehanson/KissXML) supports writing XML.

Other XML libraries that have been suggested include the XML support from [Google Data](https://github.com/google/gdata-objectivec-client) and [VTD-XML](https://vtd-xml.sourceforge.io/).

Comment: Since I need to modify the xml, what would be my best choice?

NSXMLParser is read-only, so it doesn't count

I read at one forum that TouchXML has read-write support, but I haven't found a way to write to my xml yet, and while I was looking I saw in another forum that TouchXML is just for reading, and doesn't support writting, I'm very confused about it.

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a DOM XML parser, which is best for modification of XML documents. See for example [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/725/how-to-read-and-write-xml-documents-with-gdataxml) tutorial - without mapping to and from Model Objects - use the XPath.